# Formula for number of intersection points for Lissajous curve?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Hi all:

I'm wondering if there is a simple formula for this.

Simple Example:

```
x=cos(pt);
y=cos(qt);
where p,q are integers.
```

Question: How many intersection points are there?

0) only need to consider (p,q) are relatively prime.

1) Firstly, I thought it was just basic counting:

Let N(p,q) be the number of crossing.

```
If p is odd, q is odd: N(p,q) = p(q-1) + (p-1)q = 2pq - p - q. 
If p is even, q is odd: N(p,q) = (p-1)(q-1)/2.
```

But later I found some special cases p=2,q=5,where the intersection becomes unusual and the formula falls down.

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, all the references I have that I checked (e.g. Shikin's "Handbook and Atlas of Curves") give the very unhelpful "the number of nodes is finite and depends on the value of m and n." On the other hand, they all consider the more general case that m and n are rational (for irrational values, the curve has infinitely many nodes and does not close on itself.).

Comment: If $p=2, q=5$, your second formula applies, $N(2,5)=(2-1)(5-1)/2=2$, which when you draw out $x=cos(2t)$ and $y=cos(5t)$, shows 2 intersections which is what your formula predicts.  Also, you changed variables from $m,n$ above to $p,q$ below; perhaps change that to consistently use the same variables if that is what you meant.

Comment: Consider that for the node to self-intersect, $x(t+\tau_i)=x(t)$ and $y(t+\tau_i)=y(t)$.  Consider this for $gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment:  @Eminemya, the web site you point to uses a parametrized Lissajous curve defined by y=sin(mt),x=sin(nt) while your question uses a different definition. The site also uses a constant you can add in, but it's easier if you stay consistent with your definitions.  Your question, however, poses the question with an even cosine function, y=cos(mt),x=cos(nt) which yields a different number of intersections. Could you clarify and edit your question? Also, you change variables from m,n at first, to p,q later. Could you please fix that also? Thanks.

Comment: sorry about my slopiness...Thanks for everyone's considerations:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: with both functions switched to cosine I get $$ \frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{2}  $$ for both odd-odd and for even-odd.

ORIGINAL, both functins sine: For $p$ even and $q$ odd I get $$ 2 p q - p - q  $$ which is the same as you have when both are odd.

Examples, I had to count over a few times,
(p,q,count) :

(2,1,1); (2,3,7); (2,5,13); (2,7,19);

(4,1,3); (4,3,17); (4,5,31); (4,7,45);

(6,1,5); (6,5,49); (6,7,71); (6,11,115);

Then for both odd I get $$ \frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{2}  $$

(1,q,0);

(3,q, q-1);

(5,q, 2 q - 2);

(7,q, 3 q - 3);

However for both odd the figure is traced twice, there is no way around that, look on the website you supplied and slowly vary the maximum of $\Theta.$ So it is also reasonable to claim that both segments are doubled and what appears to be a single intersection counts as four as far as the parameter values are concerned. If you prefer that, the formula for both odd becomes
$$ 2 p q - 2 p - 2 q + 2.  $$

Comment: @Will Jagy, your $(p,q,count)$ triplets are valid for a parametrized Lissajous curve defines as $y=sin(mt), x=cos(nt)$, which is the parametric definition used on the web site referred to in the question.  The question itself, however, poses the question with an even $cosine$ function, $y=cos(mt), x=cos(nt)$ which yields a different number of intersections.

Comment: obviously, I meant "defined" rather than "defines" in my comment above.

Comment: sleepless, there is a saying from the old country that covers this situation: Well, that blows.

Comment: @Will Jagy, that's pretty colourful language in that old country of yours.  :)  I think the questioner is just unclear on what they're asking.  At least your conclusions are valid for the question which you answered.

Comment: also, obviously, I meant $y=sin(mt), x=sin(nt)$ in my first comment to Will.  These typos must be fully explained by my name here, alas.  For I am truly...

Comment: I used $ \sin(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \cos \theta $ and got more examples. Edited them in.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use $sin$ or $cos$ matters, as **sine** is an [odd function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) because $sin(-\theta)=-sin(\theta)$, whereas **cosine** is an [even function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_function) because $cos(-\theta)= cos(\theta)$.

If you draw a parametrized lissajous curve with $x=cos(nt), y=cos(mt)$, with n=2, m=5, you will get two intersections as I remarked in the comments above.  If you draw a parametric lissajous curve defined as $x=sin(nt), y=sin(mt)$ with n=2, m=5, you will get the 13 points of intersection that Will Jagy got above.

Your question posits a parametric Lissajous curve with an even $cosine$ function.  The website you point to draws out the example curves with an odd $sine$ function.  You should clarify exactly what you mean in your question.

Otherwise, the points I made in the comments above should help.

Consider the intersections occuring at the simultaneous constraints for multiple values of $\tau_k$, $k$ varying from $1$ to the number of intersection points:

> $cos(nt+\tau_k)=cos(t)$
>
> $cos(mt+\tau_k)=cos(t)$

I believe that if you look at the correct parametric form of the lissajous curve, your equation will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

First let us think of generic curves: 
We say that a plane curve $C$ is generic (or non-degenerate) 
if $C$ is an immersed curve in the plane having only transverse dounble points. 
A Lissajous curve with frequencies $p,q$ and phase $c$ is given by the parametrization 
$$x(t)=cos (pt+c), y(t)=cos(qt).$$
Except for some finitely many values $c$, the curve is generic. 
Let $L(p,q)$ denote such a generic Lissajous curve, indeed, 
its topological type does not depend on the generic value $c$. 
A good reference is [V. F. Jones et al, Lissajous knots, Jour. Knot Thoery and Its Ramification (1994) 121--140].

By the way, V. I. Arnold introduced three basic invariants of topological types of generic plane curves, denoted by $J^+$, $J^-$ and $St$: 
[V. I. Arnol'd, Topological Invariants of Plane Curves and Caustics, Univ. Lect. Ser. Vol. 5, Amer. Math. Soc. (1994)].
The number $d$ of double points of a generic curve is always equal to $J^+-J^-$.

For generic $L(p,q)$ with coprime $p$ and $q$, Arnold invariants are computed as follows: 
$$J^+(L(p,q))=(p-1)(q-1), J^-(L(p,q))=-pq+1,  St(L(p,q))=0,$$ 
(Sunao Kan-mura, 2002). In particular,  $d=2pq-p-q$. 
A degenerate Lissojous curve $L_0$, e.g. in case of $c=0$ as in the question, 
is doubly covered and has two singular `end' points. 
By slightly perturbing $c$, 
we obtain a generic Lissajous curve $L_c$. 
Observe how double points of $L_c$ are created, then we see the number of the intersection points of $L_0$ is $(p-1)(q-1)/2$.